# Proper map from Annulus to The Disc

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $A(0;1,2):=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:1<|z|<2\}$ denote the annulus with inner radius $1$ and outer radius $2$. Does there exists a proper non constant holomorphic map from $A(0;1,2)$ to $\mathbb{D}$ ?

Comment: I assume you mean something other than $z \mapsto z/2$? What do you mean by proper?

Comment: A map $f:X\mapsto Y$ is proper if for every compact set $K\subset Y$, $f^{-1}(K)$ is compact in $X$.The map $z\mapsto z/2$ is not proper.

Comment: An equivalent definition which I find easy to check is that if you choose a sequence in the domain which converges to the boundary the image sequence does not have a limit point in the Range. In the case of the map $z\mapsto z/2$ if you consider a sequence converging to 1 the image sequence converges inside and hence it can't be proper.

Comment: Yes it is! Note that $f$ is continuous, so for each closed set $K \subseteq \Bbb D, f^{-1}(K)$ is closed in $A(0; 1, 2)$ Since both are bounded, the inverse image of each compact subset of $\Bbb D$ is compact in $A(0; 1 ,2)$.

Comment: @ walcher See the inverse image of the interval $[\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}].$ It's $(1,\frac{3}{2}]$, it is closed but not compact.

Comment: I mean it is closed in annulus and not in $\mathbb{C}.$

Comment: Oh, I see, I thought $A(0; 1, 2)$ includes the boundaries.

Comment: @ walcher oh yeah there is a chance of misunderstanding now I defined it in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. An example is the Ahlfors function, see e.g. my answer [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95570/does-constant-modulus-on-boundary-of-annulus-imply-constant-function/95581#95581).
In fact, we have the following Theorem due to Bieberbach, which says that there are many proper holomorphic maps onto the unit disk.

**Theorem**
Let $X$ be a domain in $\mathbb{C}_{\infty}$ bounded by disjoint analytic Jordan curves $E_1, E_2, \dots, E_n$, and let $p \in X$. For each $j$, fix a point $\alpha_j \in E_j$. Then there is a unique proper holomorphic map $f:X \to \mathbb{D}$ such that $f(\alpha_j)=1$ for all $j$ and $f(p)$=0.

For more information about proper holomorphic mappings, see the preprint [there](http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.5042).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and references.

Comment: @Abelvikram : You're welcome.