# If $\lvert f(z) \rvert$ remains constant along a circle $\lvert z \rvert = r$, then $f(z)$ is of this form $f(z) = c\cdot z^n$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Prove or give a counterexample to this:
>
> $f(z)$ is an analytic function on domain D containing some circle $\lvert z \rvert = r$. If $\lvert f(z) \rvert$ remains constant along $\lvert z \rvert = r$, then $f(z)$ is of this form $f(z) = c\cdot z^n$ where $c$ is a complex constant.

Intuitively I think it's right, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: The question as stated isn't correct, e.g. $f(z) \equiv 1$.  Also, what is $D$?  What if it doesn't contain any circle $|z| = r$?  You probably need to assume that $0 \in D$.

Comment: $\mathbb{D}$ is a fairly standard way to represent the unit ball, usually open.

Comment: for $f(z) \equiv 1$, just let c = 1 and n = 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint for a counterexample. Consider the map
$$B(z)=e^{i\theta}\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{z-a_k}{1-\overline{a}_k z}\quad \mbox{with $|a_k|<1$, for $k=1,\dots,n$ }$$
 ($B$ is called [finite Blaschke product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaschke_product#Finite_Blaschke_products)).

Show that $|B(z/r)|=1$ when $|z|=r$. It suffices to verify that for $|z|=1$,
$$\left|z-a_k|=|{1-\overline{a}_k z}\right|.$$

P.S. As remarked by mrf, if $D=\mathbb{C}$ then the property holds. For a proof see [Characterizing nonconstant entire functions with modulus 1 on the unit circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3408/characterizing-nonconstant-entire-functions-with-modulus-1-on-the-unit-circle)

Comment: sorry, haven't learned Blaschke product. is there another way easier?

Comment: Forget the name "Blaschke product". Consider the map $M(z)=\frac{z-a}{1-\overline{a} z}$ and show that $|M(z)|=1$ along $|z|=1$.

Comment: another related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2455505/lvert-c-n-rvert-frac-max-lvert-z-rvert-r-vert-fz-rvert-rn

Comment: Just for completeness, if $D=\mathbb{C}$, i.e. if $f$ is entire, the conclusion actually holds.

Comment: @mrf How to prove it?

Comment: @Hongyan See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3408/characterizing-nonconstant-entire-functions-with-modulus-1-on-the-unit-circle

Comment: If I reinforce the condition: along every circle $\lvert z \rvert = r$ in $\Bbb D$,  $\lvert f(z) \rvert$ remains constant. Is there any chance of the statement being true?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95570/does-constant-modulus-on-boundary-of-annulus-imply-constant-function?rq=1 So the answer is yes as soon as the function is constant on $|z|=r_1>0$ and on $|z|=r_2>r_1$ and it does not vanish in the annulus.