# $\lvert c_n \rvert = \frac {\max_{\lvert z \rvert = r} \vert f(z) \rvert} {r^n} (0 \lt r \lt R)$ then, $f(z)$ is of this form $f(z) = c_n*z^n$.

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

$f(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty c_nz^n$, $ \lvert z \rvert \lt R$. If at least one $c_n$ satisfies the following equation: $$\lvert c_n \rvert = \frac {\max_{\lvert z \rvert = r} \vert f(z) \rvert} {r^n} (0 \lt r \lt R)$$

then, $f(z)$ is of this form $f(z) = c_n*z^n$.

From [Cauchy's integral formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) we know $\lvert c_n \rvert \le \frac {\max_{\lvert z \rvert = r} \vert f(z) \rvert} {r^n}$, the only case in which the inequality becomes equality I think is when $\lvert f(z) \rvert$ is constant along $\lvert z \rvert = r$. Then I tried to [deduce the form from here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2455436/if-lvert-fz-rvert-remains-constant-along-a-circle-lvert-z-rvert-r-t), but failed.

Comment: But the property that you want use is *false*...

Comment: @Hongyan Did you read the answer ? Your [linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2455436/if-lvert-fz-rvert-remains-constant-along-a-circle-lvert-z-rvert-r-t) isn't correct, so don't try to reuse it here !!!

Comment: Here the solution is to multiply by $e^{i \theta}$ to obtain $c_n =\Re(\frac{1}{2i\pi} \int_{|z| = r} \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz)$

Comment: Of course I read the answer, so I said "failed". But I didn't get your solution, can you explain it a little more?

Comment: You said $|c_n| =  \frac{|f(z)|}{|z^{n}|}$ for $|z| = r$. I added another condition.

Comment: @Hongyan Do you mean that for at least one $n$ the property $|c_n|=\frac{\mathrm{max}_{|z|=r}|f(z)|}{r^n}$ holds for all $0<r<R$ or just for one $r$ such that $0<r<R$. If you mean the first, I think I know a solution. For the later, I am not sure if the conclusion is true.

Comment: @user213008 I think it's the first. Put your solution out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you use the Cauchy inequality for the coefficients $0\leq m<n$, and find that
$$
|c_m|\leq\frac{\mathrm{max}_{|z|=r}|f(z)|}{r^m}=\frac{\mathrm{max}_{|z|=r}|f(z)|}{r^n}\cdot r^{n-m}=|c_n|r^{n-m}
$$
for all $0<r<R$. Since $n-m>0$, if you let $r\to 0$, you find that $c_m=0$ for all $0\leq m<n$. In other words, the singularity of $g(z)=f(z)/z^n$ at $0$ is removable, and you have defined a holomorphic function $g$ on $\{|z|<r\}$. We cleary have $\sup_{|z|<r}|g(z)|=|c_n|$. On the other hand, we also have
$$
g(z)=c_n+c_{n+1}z+\cdots\text{ and thus }g(0)=c_n\,.
$$
This means that $g$ obtains its maximum. By the maximum modulus principle, $g$ must be constant equalt to $c_n$ everywhere on $\{|z|<r\}$. It follows that $f(z)=c_nz^n$ everywhere on $\{|z|<r\}$ and by the identity theorem everywhere on $\{|z|<R\}$.

Comment: Nice!..........